# TextureAtlas has worse filtering than Texture?

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, texture-atlas

When I filter image with the texture.setFilter(linear, linear), it gets filtered perfectly. But when I put it in a textureatlas, the filter is worse and i can still see pixelation.

I tried the approach below, which didnt work

```
Sprite sprite = atlas.createSprite("image");
sprite.getTexture().setFilter(linear, linear); // pseudo code
image = sprite;
```

I also tried to edit the .pack file to set filter to: (which didn't work either)

```
filter: Linear, Linear
```

Please suggest reasons for these to fail?

Comment: Do you use TexturePacker? If so please try to set linear filtering type **during atlas creation** not after in .pack file

Comment: You can edit the pack file after creation also